# Is it possible to have a civilization after the year 15000?

Tags: civilization, far-future

In my context, the year 15000 is important but I was wondering if there is a chance to have existing civilizations around this year (or after) ?

Based on the [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpj0E0a0mlU) video, if we keep growing at our current rate, we would consume the whole matter of the universe after around 10000years, can this really be?

Comment: The population will obviously not continue to grow at 1% a year until we have consumed all the matter in the universe. The growth rate is self-limiting in the long term as we outpace available resources.

Comment: There are a *lot* of barriers to us growing at a constant exponential rate.  As a parable, think about why there's world hunger - we can grow enough food for everyone on Earth, but we can't distribute it to everyone.  Now imagine trying to get all our human particles out of a gravity well, rather than just across it.  Regardless, a lot of particles are going to remain inaccessible, unless less you have a sun-mersible I don't know about

Comment: Past performance is no warranty for the future. Not only for bank investments.

Comment: There's a couple of issues with that video because it focuses on the observable universe, to start with it ignores the fact that we can only see an estimated 10% of the universe, the rest of it is "Dark Matter" and "Dark Energy" which have a physical effect but we can't see them. The observable universe also grows year on year as well as light reaches us from farther and farther away.

Comment: One of the first science-fiction novels I read as a teenager was titled *A Love Story of the Year 41,042*. So, obviously, it's imaginable. What's certain is that we will eventually stop growing; we will either live in a steady-state society, or else we'll face a crash.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, toto! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6168) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods. Have fun!

Comment: I just want to point out that there is no way we will continue to grow at our current rate for the next 10000 years. It is normal for species populations to explode and then shrink heavily from death/starvation/etc.

Comment: Yes, as civilization pushes against the limit, increasing poverty and famine will reduce the number of children who successfully grow up and reproduce.

Answer (score 4):

Easily, space is really really dangerous, and it takes no prisoners, it just kills anyone who isn't paying attention, or who gets even slightly unlucky. I can foresee no scenario in which we will continue to grow at anything like our current continuous rate once we routinely live in space, planetary populations might keep growing but space living populations are going to be prey to "extreme attrition". Radiation is going to render a lot of people who work in space either actively sterile or at least not fit as breeders, vacuum is going to kill people almost every day (habitats in a vacuum are open to catastrophic failure and acts of sabotage that can kill populations that would require you to purge whole earthly continents). May be I'm a pessimist but I very much doubt we'll ever breed into all the space and matter available to us.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as space travel goes. We haven't sent anyone into space further than the IIS for a long time. That could change though, so there's a small chance we could expand outside our planet. If not then we are a self-destructive species. Right now we're living in a time of relative peace, but that's propped up by some alliances that wont last forever. What happens when that fails or if big nations fail? We're polluting the planet and our system of society depends on constant growth. That growth has to end somewhere. We're using up all the worlds resources. People are becoming so dependent on technology that they wont know how to survive or progress without it. I don't see humanity lasting any longer than 1000 years as is. Maybe something will happen to reset everything, like a major volcanic eruption, a war, a chemical disaster or an asterioid collision. If enough of humanity was wiped out then the world would have some time to recuperate and mankind would have less impact on the planet. Minimising the population could be mankind's only hope of survival. Then you would have civilisation, but not on the grand scale that it is now. If space travel becomes feasible then this would change, but space is very hostile. That's why we've never gone beyond the moon. Most suitable places aren't easily reachable and setup in closer places would present a lot of challenges, like protection from heat/cold, oxygen, production of water etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no known reason we could not be around in 15,000 years.

Exponential curves always fall short.  They are only valid in environments where one's effect on the environment is negligible.  A [S-curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) is typically a much better model for real life situations.  For example, yeast freshly pitched in a bucket of soon-to-be-beer exhibits exponential growth.  It does this for a very short period of time.  Then it starts to consume enough of the resources in the beer to limit its own growth.  It ends up following a S-curve, roughly.

15,000 years is a *long* time from a civilization perspective.  History has only been going for about 7,000 years, and we typically define the start of civilization as the boundary between history and pre-history.  So you're talking twice as long as we've been going.  We really can't say where we'll end up.  It's just too far.  That's not to say we can't survive that long, just that it's remarkably difficult to predict *anything* about what it will be like.

However, 15,000 years is a *pittance* on geologic or galactic scales.  H. sapiens has been around almost 7 times that long, and we're considered a mere momentary lapse of reason on geological timescales.  When you start talking about civilization living for 500 million years, now we're starting to talk about fun geological issues.  When you start talking about civilization living 5-10 billion years, now we're talking about fun galactic issues.  15,000 is a blink of an eye for such systems.